# Is there a solidity string limit of 32 bytes?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I know there was a string limit but I thought that was long ago. I had a smart contract working but there is a limit of 32 bytes on the string input. I am unsure if  a version changed or something like that. I had tested before and it was handling strings longer than 32 bytes. Now it does not.

When that is exceeded it does not insert any data. I ma using PoA now, I was testing with PoW before. But that should not make any difference.

I am running addInventory in the following contract.

Can someone clarify the allowed string length?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

// this contract stores the inventory strings, the hash of the string, and the keys to storage areas
// to add - events for updates, sha to check passed sha (if an error reject),

contract RegisterContract {

    uint public inventoryWeight;

    mapping(bytes32=>string) public inventories; // stores of json strings
    bytes32[] public inventoryHashes; // this is used mainly in testing eg inventoryHashes(uint) for the sequence of inventories added
    bytes32[] public inventoryHashesStorage; // keys to storage

    event eventNewInventory(bytes32 hashInventory);
    event eventNewStorageInventory(bytes32 hashInventory);

    function addInventory ( string inventory, bytes32 hashInventory) public {
        inventories[hashInventory] = inventory;
        inventoryHashes.push(hashInventory);
        eventNewInventory(hashInventory);
     }

     function addInventoryHash(bytes32 hashInventory) public {
         // storage key - kept separate in case add addInventory fails due to gas limits
         // during testing addInventory did sometimes fail due to long strings
         // this hashInventory would be a key to IPFS or a database
         inventoryHashesStorage.push(hashInventory);
         eventNewStorageInventory(hashInventory);
     }

    function getAllInventories() public view returns (bytes32[]) {
        return inventoryHashesStorage;
    }

    function addWeight (uint weight) public {
        inventoryWeight = weight;
    }

    function () payable public {
    }

}
```

Comment: This works on Ropsten. So it is a geth issue.

Answer (score 6):

A variable of type `bytes32` can't contain strings longer than 32 characters.

A variable of type `string` can contain a string of any size.

Do you have a reproduceable example where a `string` can't contain more than 32 characters? Maybe an etherscan link to a transaction on your contract?

Comment: I can send the connection details, if you have a PM here.

Comment: > f1="jkhdfkjsdhfjdshkhskjghdfjkghkjdfhgjkdfhgkjfhgkjdfhgkjfhdgkjfhgkjfhgkjf"
"jkhdfkjsdhfjdshkhskjghdfjkghkjdfhgjkdfhgkjfhgkjdfhgkjfhdgkjfhgkjfhgkjf"
> eth.defaultAccount=eth.coinbase
"0x0c12901e1ec7f80763cd433e8eca0c837d11a0c1"
> con.addInventory(f1, web3.sha3(f1))
"0x8d506679b06d4d6cb4a81e0ab53f5a0abe7abfb12f7bb1cd04764c8bdc444eb9"
> con.inventories(web3.sha3(f1))
""
> f1="hjkfhgfjghfjkg"
"hjkfhgfjghfjkg"
> con.addInventory(f1, web3.sha3(f1))
"0x737419aff198c110d3290e33bd5f0897c885983ebc57d41cd8b547f0df8c6858"
> con.inventories(web3.sha3(f1))
"hjkfhgfjghfjkg"
>

Comment: I would like to clarify that, while in practice it is a *string of any size*, there is actually a limit of `2^256 * 256` bits or about 3.7 * 10^54 [yottabytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yottabyte).

Comment: Technically it's `(2^256 -1)*256` because of length encoding

Comment: If you're going to consider that a limit, you should consider lots of other limitations (hard drive size, network speed, transaction fee, etc) which all cause even lower limits :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the hashes pushed into the array are longer than 32bytes. Btw, wouldn't it better to save the hashes in a mapping instead?

Comment: Hashes are all 32 bytes. There is a mapping already.

Comment: web3.sha3(f1) is 66bytes "0x" included or 64bytes without "0x" prefix

Comment: @siid That is the hexadecimal notation used in javascript, when encoded in a raw transaction it is just 32 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Gas cost - 
 commodityContract.addInventory(mystrS, shastr, {gas: 4712000});
   commodityContract.addInventoryHash(shastr,{gas: 4712000});

Comment: If this was intended to answer the question, please edit it to clarify how it answers the question that was asked.